# Adding a NavigationBar to UITableViewController programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to create a uitableviewcontroller as a modal viewcontroller to edit some settings. I am creating the tableviewcontroller in code and the thing i am struggling with currently is how to correctly add a navigation bar to the controller which will have a "Done" button on it that:

a) doesnt appear on top of the tableview and 
b) does not scroll with the tableview??

This happens when i add the navbar to the contoller with:
[self.view addSubview:navigationBar];
This adds a navbar to the controller which goes on top and obscures the tables first row and also scrolls with the view?

I also thought about simply using a uiviewcontroller with a separate tableview however i like the funcitonality of automatically scrolling the tableview when editing a textfield that the tableviewcontroller gives you. Just cant figure how to setup this navbar??

thx

Answer (score 9):

Just create UINavigationcontroller as the modal viewcontroller, and add the tableview as its root view controller.

Comment: Thx, maybe i not understanding correctly but this seems similar to just using a uiviewcontroller instead of a uitableviewcontroller. I would like to use a uitableviewcontroller so i dont have to worry about scrolling/resizing the view when the user tries to edit one of the textfields which the keyboard may obscure.

Comment: @Tony: when you create the modal view controller, also create a `UINavigationController` and add the view controller to it.  Then, present the navigation controller.

Answer (score 7):

Use Navigation controller as modalviewController(as suggested in the other answer). Here is the code:

```
UINavigationController *Controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
            //LoginViewController is a sub class of UITableviewController
        LoginViewController *controller = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
        Controller.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObject:controller];

        [self presentModalViewController:Controller animated:YES];
        [controller release];
        [Controller release];
```

Answer (score -1):

In **Swift**:

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
       /*
          #1. Instantiate a navigation controller and add the table view controller 
          as a child view controller.
       */
       let navigationController = UINavigationController()
       // Instantiate your desired ViewController
       let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: UIStoryboardName.Main.rawValue, bundle: nil)
       let tableViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TableViewControllerID")
                    navigationController.addChildViewController(tableViewController)

       /*
          #2. Then we set the title of the navigation bar and add two bar button items.
       */
       // We set the title of the navigation bar.
       tableViewController.navigationItem.title = "My Title"

       // Create left and right button for navigation item.
       let leftButton =  UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style:  UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: tableViewController, action: "saveButtonClicked:")
       let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Right", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)

       // Create two buttons for the navigation item.
       tableViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
       tableViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton

       /*
           #3. To finish we set the root view controller with the navigation controller.
       */            
       self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
       self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

       return true
    }
```

**TableViewController.swift**

```
    // Method called when the user clicks on the Save bar button item.
    func saveButtonClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        // Do something.
        print("Save bar button item has been clicked!!!")
    }
```