# Adding a navigation bar to UITableView programmatically

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I am new to  IOS ..

What I want is to have a navigation bar over a `UITableView`, which I created inside `-(void) loadView`

My code goes like this ...

```
(void)loadView {
    [super loadView];       

    CGRect  frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480); //define size and position of view
    tableView1= [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:frame style:UITableViewStylePlain ];
    tableView1.editing=YES;
    tableView1.dataSource=self;
    tableView1.delegate=self;

    //navigationItem= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Names" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(first:) ];
    //self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=btnBarItem;

    [self.view addSubview:tableView1];
}
```

I want navigation bar over the tableview I allocated so that I can insert a add button..

Any help will be highly appreciated ...

Comment: What happend does it solve your problem :) ???????????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a NavigationBar to UITableViewController programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700990/adding-a-navigationbar-to-uitableviewcontroller-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

[Adding a NavigationBar to UITableViewController programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700990/adding-a-navigationbar-to-uitableviewcontroller-programmatically)

Check that out first, it's the exact same question. Also, @anka is right. Just push the UITableViewController as the rootview in your NavigationController. If you don't know how to, click `Editor -> Embed in -> Navigation Controller`, that's the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are new to iOS development I don't know if you are familiar with the navigation patterns within iOS.

Look at the documentation of [Navigation Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH2-SW1) and then you should use a `UINavigationViewController` and a `UITableViewController`. Push the `UITableViewController` on the `UINavigationViewController` and you have your navigation bar right on top.

Comment: thanks anka :)... this method i know but i want to know whether we can insert navigation bar directly  into tableview  without using UInavigationController ??

Comment: No it's not possible but you can put navigation bar in view :)

Answer (score 0):

Just put this code

Have to remove it as it is just cause error :)

**Edit 1**

sorry for miss understanding. Here is the solution that works.

You need to take the UINavigationController as the main container in appDelegate and assign your first viewController to it's root viewController as I have done before in the code like

```
UINavigationController *ePicker = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
```

and then you will get navigation bar on your tableview

Happy Coding :)

**Edit 2**

If you just want a navigation bar not a navigationViewController then just put this lines

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc]init];
    [self.view addSubview:navBar];
```

in viewDidLoad method and the navigation bar will be shown above the tabelView

Happy Coding :)

Comment: am getting warning on   allocating( UINavigationController *nav)  incompatible Objective-C types 'struct UITableView *', expected 'struct UIViewController *' when passing argument 1 of 'initWithRootViewController:' from distinct Objective-C type .....                                                                                                                                and( [self.view addSubview:nav];
) incompatible Objective-C types 'struct UINavigationController *', expected 'struct UIView *' when passing argument 1 of 'addSubview:' from distinct Objective-C type

Comment: thanks dude ..is there any option without using container and all?

Comment: yes just see my answer with edit 2 this will show what you want :)

Comment: @indiekiduk what exactly you trying to do? Please elaborate some more or put line of code will surly guide you :)