# How can i add a navigation bar to presentModalViewController programmatically?

Tags: ios, uitableview, presentmodalviewcontroller

How can i add a navigation bar to presentModalViewController programmatically?
I know default navigation bar will be there in pushViewController..
hope your help...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a NavigationBar to UITableViewController programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700990/adding-a-navigationbar-to-uitableviewcontroller-programmatically)

Comment: UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableViewController] autorelease];
    [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES]; try this

Comment: You can add the navigation bar  to xib file directly from  the interface builder by drag and drop.

Comment: @Vinu1991 The question specifically asks how to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make use of this code in viewDidLoad.

```
UINavigationBar *myBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:myBar];
```

This will add navigation bar to your view.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you

```
PopoverView *foo = [[PopoverView alloc] initWithNibName:@"PopoverView" bundle:nil];
 // Here you pass through properties if you need too.
 // ...
 UINavigationController *navC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootView:foo];
 [foo release];

 [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navC animated:YES];
```

That is how you add a nav bar to modal.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your View did load

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

Comment: I don't know, this didn't work for me. I tried both in viewDidLoad, and when the presenting view controller instantiates the presented controller